ReactiveUI Router.NavigateAndReset don't work on Android
Below I'll describe the case where routing isn't working when I try to switch Views on Android (AvaloniaUI). I see that new viewmodel is created but the view remains the same. The exact same code works fine under windows desktop project.
Avalonia 11.1.0-rc2
Need a bit of help to find out how to make it work. Thanks.
The call to router made from LoginViewModel, VM is created here but no view change:
HostScreen.Router.NavigateAndReset.Execute(new MainViewModel()).Subscribe();

Bootstraper, where I set the IScreen:
public class BootstrapRouter : ReactiveObject, IScreen
{
    public RoutingState Router { get; }

    public BootstrapRouter()
    {
        Router = new RoutingState();
        ConfigureViews();
        ConfigureServices();
    }

    private void ConfigureViews()
    {
        Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant(this, typeof(IScreen));
        Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterViewsForViewModels(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices()
    {
        Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterLazySingleton(() => new AppSettings(), typeof(IAppSettings));
        Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterLazySingleton(() => new DbContext(), typeof(IDbContext));
        Locator.CurrentMutable.UseSerilogFullLogger();
    }
}

App class:
public partial class App : Application
{

public override void Initialize()
{
    //initialize DI
    AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
}

public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
{
    //initialize bootstrap and all loadings
    _ = new BootstrapRouter();

    if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
    {
        var wnd = desktop.MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        wnd.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
    else if (ApplicationLifetime is ISingleViewApplicationLifetime singleViewPlatform)
    {
        var v = singleViewPlatform.MainView = new LoginView();
        v.DataContext = new LoginViewModel();
    }

    base.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();
}
}

LoginViewModel and MainViewModel are based on this:
public abstract class RoutableViewModelBase : ReactiveObject, IRoutableViewModel
{
    public abstract string UrlPathSegment { get; }

    public IScreen HostScreen { get; }

    protected RoutableViewModelBase()
    {
        HostScreen = Locator.Current.GetService<IScreen>();
    }
}


Found the problem :) Design issue. The problem is for mobile android the main view is set to var v = singleViewPlatform.MainView = new LoginView(); which do not have RoutedViewHost component in XAML responsible for routing.
I made a new main host view for mobile similar to MainWindow and now it work.
